# Android Koin, How to make Repository using two DataSource?

Tags: android, kotlin, koin

I am trying to make an Android toy project using a Koin.

My project has one Repository and two DataSources (remote/cache).

Here are DataSources:

```
interface DataSource

class CacheDataSource: DataSource

class RemoteDataSource: DataSource
```

And here is Repository:

```
interface MyRepository

class MyRepositoryImpl(
    val cacheDataSource: DataSource,
    val remoteDataSource: DataSource
): MyRepository
```

So... I am writing the appModule code like:

```
val appModule = module {
    single<DataSource>(StringQualifier("cache")) { CacheDataSource() }
    single<DataSource>(StringQualifier("remote")) { RemoteDataSource() }
    single<MyRepository> { MyRepositoryImpl() as MyRepository by inject("???") }
}
```

And...

I tried below code too...:

```
val appModule = module {
    single<DataSource>(StringQualifier("cache")) { CacheDataSource() }
    single<DataSource>(StringQualifier("remote")) { RemoteDataSource() }
    single<MyRepository> { MyRepositoryImpl(get<MoviesDataSource>(name = "cache"), get<MoviesDataSource>(name = "remote")) }
}
```

But I don't know how should I do this?

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution...

```
val appModule = module {
    single<DataSource>(StringQualifier("cache")) { CacheDataSource() }
    single<DataSource>(StringQualifier("remote")) { RemoteDataSource() }
    single<MyRepository> { MyRepositoryImpl(get(StringQualifier("cache")), get(StringQualifier("remote"))) }
}
```

Comment: How would you do to group many dataSources under 'fake' and 'real' qualifiers? I'm getting koin error because qualifier are like IDs and it's not possible to have multiple.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this too:

```
val appModule = module {
    single<CacheDataSource> { CacheDataSource() }
    single<RemoteDataSource> { RemoteDataSource() }
    single<MyRepository> { MyRepositoryImpl(get(), get()) }
}
```